# Удалить текст в одной строке по маске bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Добрый день. Возникла такая задача. 
Скрипт формирует строку.

`[[["2c5d5aa063cbd80120ff8c666d8e6032d006ce7f","1","77459"],["","1",""],["","1",""],],[]]`

Нужно пройтись по файлу и удалить все `["","1",""],` то есть пустые, не нужные мне значения.
строка должна принять вид (количество записей может меняться)

```
[[["6a826cae5c354769f6ace3659becdea6e24bbcb0", "1", "30000"],["069ac71a9e9946522cbd08d50735a6752a9fe2aa", "1", "17000"],["69a0ad6441314c9e91b885b283310d9786a3fdeb", "1", "30000"],["4509266c765f6c76e0142671c575f81243ea09f1", "1", "30000"],["a5e705c376f61185648cb51f0e62fb9319aca036", "1", "44000"],["a928e660e6ae5e07c031dbcd448379f0e976e11a", "1", "23000"],["c1455a28696c05d29dbcc52a6b7c0b2cf6d69d28", "1", "21000"],["ed2a033e270dd240903a1e039d388324aedc5f63", "1", "32000"],["f905d4e71b253d6fe3e77f2abc33d21412805c8b", "1", "77000"]], []]
```

Значение в строке соответственно могут быть разными и не должны меняться после работы скрипта

Comment: `sed 's/\["","1",""\],\?//g' имя-файла`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/\["","1",""\],? *//g' -i filename
```

Если нужно ещё убрать лишние запятые перед закрывающей скобкой:

```
sed -r 's/\["","1",""\],? *//g; s/,\]/]/g' -i filename
```

Comment: Отлично, работает. Спасибо.

Comment: Входящий поток очень похож на JSON или питоновские списки, легче и корректней делать разбор формата, а потом уже процессить.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko приведите пример как это реализовать в shell

Comment: Я про shell не уточнял, shell для этого просто неудобный (неправильно выбранный) инструмент.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko, задача из одного файла получить другой, больше ничего делать не требуется, ваш вариант займёт в любом случае больше строк и времени на программирование.

Comment: Я всё время вспоминаю, когда один вопрошающий как-то хотел на shell из HTML (xml) документа определённые строки вырезать. Поэтому все эти костыли рано или поздно до добра не доведут.

Comment: Да, на питоне по примеру очень можно уложиться в пару строк кода, ну или для новичка в 10к.